# Deleting with a trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am importing a spreadsheet once a week that is filled with all the training that we do as a company, some of which is mandatory some of which is not. Am i able to make a trigger to get rid of the mandatory training.

```
delete from [import training]
where module not in ('Mandatory Training 1','Mandatory Training 2' etc...)
```

As an example of what the code would look like, but will it work as a trigger when I have the correct syntax around it?

Comment: You can put any SQL statement you like in a trigger. Whether you should is another matter. It seems unlikely that you want to run a `DELETE` on the entire table every time a row is inserted, and more likely that you want to pre-filter inserted rows (which is better suited to an `INSTEAD OF` trigger operating on the `inserted` pseudo-table).

Comment: Why did you ask this question instead of just trying it?

Comment: I agree with Jeroen Mostert. Dont need a Trigger for something like this. Since its a weekly process, why dont you create an SSIS package to import the data and then add another task to DELETE the data after?

Comment: @mvisser Now that SSIS is involved. How about a conditional split on the data flow to remove the unwanted records before loading to the table.

Comment: Oh that's how you get rid of mandatory training... and maybe what you're looking for is `merge`. With it you can insert  / update / delete rows from a target table based on a  source table.

Comment: The reason why I am wanting a trigger is because it will be imported by an API rather than done manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will work, but first consider the following options:

- Filter the data before doing the insert.
- Implement a `CHECK` constraint with the accepted values only. This will force all non-valid values to be rejected with the whole insert/update.
- Keep all data but filter when you access it, with a condition on a `WHERE` or a view.

If the previous options are not appropriate, then you can create an `INSTEAD OF` trigger like Jeroen mentioned, which will rewrite the insert operation just with the valid values. You will also need to consider updates of this field.

```
CREATE TRIGGER OnlyMandatoryTrainings ON [import training] 
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO [import training] (
        module 
        -- All remaining columns
        )
    SELECT
        module
        -- All remaining columns
    FROM
        inserted AS I
    WHERE
        I.module IN ('valid value 1', 'valid value 2')

END
```

Using triggers to implement business logic isn't a good practice, although there might be a few exceptions every now and then. I would try to avoid them as much as possible, if not then problems such as "my rows aren't being inserted but the insert doesn't fail" arises.

Answer (score 0):

Why delete the mandatory training?

Instead, create a view:

```
create view optional_training as
    select t.*
    from [import training] t
    where t.module not in ('Mandatory Training 1','Mandatory Training 2' etc...);
```

Then, someone can query the view to get the optional training.  They can query the base table to get all training.